# GWT buttonbar toolbar appears as dropdown in Chrome (other browsers have separate buttons)

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt, cross-browser, toolbar

In Edge, the toolbar buttons on this panel display individually, but in Chrome they are bunched into a ">>" button.  Is there anything I can do to make Chrome display them the same as Edge?  This code is 4 years old.  Anecdotally, it was fine in Chrome until recently (I can't be sure).

[image: Edge]

[image: Chrome]

Code:

```
        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
        toolBar.add(okButton);
        toolBar.add(cancelButton);
        toolBar.add(addButton);
        toolBar.add(deleteButton);
        toolBar.add(copyButton);

        FramedPanel panel = new FramedPanel();
        panel.setHeading(p_ChartDTO.getChartName() + " - Chart Series");
        panel.add(m_ChartQueryGrid);
        panel.getButtonBar().add(toolBar);
        panel.setSize("800px", "350px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used these classes such as `Toolbar`, but it looks like if the horizontal size of the contents exceeds a certain threshold it renders it in a popup menu instead.

If part of the styling is not specified it will come from the default stylesheet of the browser.  Perhaps recent versions of Chrome changed a style size slightly and this has affected `Toolbar` so that the total size has exceeded some threshold.

If you remove 1 button, or reduce the length of a button's text (e.g. change "Delete" to "D") does it take on the desired behaviour in Chrome?

If this is the case, perhaps specifying the size of the `Toolbar` or `ButtonBar` may help, as the default is insufficient.

Comment: Bingo.  Fixed with toolBar.setWidth().  Thank you Robert.